# Where to learn what ratios to use in cooking?

Tags: measurements, resources

I am learning to cook. I want to know whether there is a good resource at what ratios of ingredients to use when I am cooking. Thank You. :)

Comment: please, add here the label "quantitative". I want to know more about this kind of questions. Excellent question! +1

Comment: I don't see how "quantitative" is useful as a tag. We have a search in the upper-right-hand corner; try searching for "ratio" or "measurements".

Comment: @hhh I can't add tag I don't have enought points. I tried to add tag "measurements", Hope that helps. Should I keep it?

Comment: user712092: yes I think that is a good idea. Well, it does not fully address similar questions but at least it does describe this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about Ruhlman's book, [Ratio: The Simple Codes Behind the Craft of Everyday Cooking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416571728)?

The entire work is dedicated to breaking cooking down into ratios, and it includes recipes.  I hear the bread recipe is particularly good.

Comment: I can vouch for his batters. The doughs are good too. The sauces are a bit thick for my taste, but this is easily remedied once the starting point is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I will outline some tips in the book suggested by BobMcGee:

1. use weight measurements in using ratios. Do not use volumetric, density or anything like that.
2. have a digital scale that can measure up to 5 pounds (2.3 kg) and in grams and pounds due to the point 1.
3. 3-2-1 -rule: pie = flour:fat:water, cookie = flour:fat:sugar (look at the cover cheatsheet)
4. have at least 3 different sized liquid measuring spoons 8:4:1 (four soups, water and serving)

Answer (score 1):

The Food Network's Alton Brown show "**[Good Eats](http://www.foodnetwork.com/good-eats/index.html)**" frequently describes base recipes in form of ratios. But for this you actually have to watch the shows, when the recipes are published the ratios are replaced with measurements.